# How to create popup using only PHP?

Tags: php, popup

Actually I figured out a way to do this:
What follows isn't exactly working code, but it does convey my idea. I've implemented this idea and it does work. I think the drawback is for complex pages, because the entire page has to be reloaded every time a popup goes up or down. But, on the good side, NO MORE JAVA SCRIPTS!!! YAY!!! :)

```
<html>
<body class="classfile.css">
<div                                 <?//add background stuff here?>
<?php
if(isset($_POST["popupmode"]))
   echo ' style="opacity:0.15" '; //this will fade out any background stuff
 ?>
style="height:1000px;with:600"px>
<form method="post" action="thispage.php">
<input type="hidden" name="popupmode">
<input type="submit" value="bring up popup">
</form>
</div>

 <?php
 if(isset($_POST["popupmode"]))
  {
   echo '<div style="with:200px;height:200px;top:-800px;left:200px;border-style:raised">';
  echo '<form method="post" action="thispage.php">';
  echo '<input type="submit" value="bring down popup">';
  echo '</form></div>';
  }    
  ?>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Sorry to disappoint you mate but this is not a popup... WHy don't you try JQueryUI? really easy to create popups...

Comment: Holy crap, this is revolutionary stuff! That's just fracking amazing! Oh wait, it just reloads the page (disappointed), that's what they did in the early nineties, before we had javascript?

Comment: First off, "NO MORE JAVA SCRIPTS!!! YAY!!! :)" I'm honestly not sure how you're fitting into today's world of web development with this kind of attitude towards javascript. Secondly instead of resorting to 20 year old solutions, why not just learn javascript? It's really not that hard, even if you jump directly into a library like jQuery.

Comment: I think it is Skepticism, rather than just "Hating JavaScript". Creating a Popup in JavaScript is at least 100 times easier than that PHP. Never rely on the user, or on the user machine or whatever. Lots of hackers from the old times learned that the hard way, and throwing this knowledge away because jQuery is cool doesn't seem like a smart idea to me either.

Comment: I do java ok. This was a mental exercise more than anything else. I saw this question posted in a closed question and started thinking how you could do it only using php. It's true I don't like JS, a personal taste thing. I'm tempted to turn it off on my browser, but it breaks too many sites. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP Is Server Side. It is not very smart to reload the page to "Popup" something.

There are PURE-CSS Lightboxes, and you can use JavaScript or even your PHP solution as a FallBack, incase the broser is old. Still, it's not a very good idea. I would try a CSS Solution, since it can happen on the client.

Something like:

```
.popupBox {
    display:none;
}
.popup:hover .popupBox{
    display: block;
}
```

Or if you need clicks:

```
.popupBox {
    display:none;
}
.popupBox:target{
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: One question, not an expert on css. Your code above will bring up a popup but once the :target code runs, how do you bring down the popup?

Comment: When you click something that changes the target again.

This example may help:
http://webdesignernotebook.com/css/the-css3-target-pseudo-class-and-css-animations/